# Install + start ssh in dockerfile derived from official jenkins docker image

Tags: jenkins, ssh, docker, dockerfile

I try to build a dockerfile which is derived from the official jenkins image.
Inside this dockerfile I want to install `openssh-server` and start the `ssh` process.

I know it's possible when I clone the whole github of jenkins and change the dockerfile + startscript there but I don't want to do that.

I tried multiple things. My dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM jenkins:2.7.1
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install openssh-server
ENTRYPOINT service ssh start
```

The installation is fine. But the problem is starting the `ssh` service.
I will overwrite the (inital) command to start jenkins so Jenkins will not be started. I also want to be the default jenkins user in my container

Comment: Firstly, what do you need to run ssh for? Do you really need it? If you do want to run multiple services you'll need an init process. [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) might do. docker then has no idea if your services are running, only that supervisor is.

Comment: To re-enforce @Matt's comment, you don't need to run SSH within the Jenkins container. Instead run SSH within something like a slave container, for example: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/ssh-slave/

Comment: @MarkO'Connor So as far as I understand I have to run one jenkins container (master) and than just containers which containt jdk + ssh and than connect?

Comment: @MaxC It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. If all you need is a single master, then you don't need ssh. Jobs will run locally without an issue. If on the other hand you want to setup some Docker based slaves, then the link about is convenient as it's a Docker image that already includes both Java and SSH. On the master you just pretend it's another server and just confgure a normal SSH based slave. Hope that clarifies things.